# Why jQuery .val() don't encode &amp; to &

Tags: jquery

```
<input type="text" id="search" value=" &amp; ">
```

When loading page input will show & (that's good)

But if i use jQuery to update value of my input, lets say:

`$("#search").val(" &amp; ");` the input will show me `&amp;` (but i want to show & (but still encoded as `&amp;` in the back, like the first example))

What i m missing here?

Comment: Show where? It doesn't un-encode it because the value in your input isn't `&` it's `&amp;`. This seems perfectly correct behaviour to me. Your question really isn't very clear?

Comment: The `&amp;` inside a HTML file will have been decoded by the browser's HTML parser before it hits the rendering engine. That's part of XML/HTML. There is no such decoding happening for Javascript files. (There might be for Javascript snippets embedded in HTML).

Comment: I use autocomplete, i use htmlspecialchars to ecnode my data and return in autocomplete, lets say i will return A &amp; D company, i want my input to be populated with A & D (but value should be A &amp; D)

Comment: Value should *not* be `A &amp; D`. Value should be `A & D`. It's just that if you put that into HTML directly (as literal text), you have to use the entity for `&`.

Comment: @Thilo so is safe to use & ? insted on &amp; on input value? i'm scared of xss attacks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot protect yourself against XSS attacks solely by defending yourself against harmful user coding in the browser. I can send you a harmful request even without a browser. You need to protect yourself against XSS attacks on server-side either when you store user data or when you generate the html, depending on your approach.

This is a PHP function with which you can protect yourself against such attacks:

```
public static function protectArrayAgainstXSS(&$arr) {
    $changed = false;
    foreach ($arr as $index => $a) {
        if (is_array($a)) {
            $changed = $changed || Common::protectArrayAgainstXSS($arr[$index]);
        } else if ($a !== null) {
            $changed = $changed || ($arr[$index] === strip_tags($a));
            $arr[$index] = strip_tags($a);
        }
    }
    return !$changed;
}
```

Your code should run this whenever it wants to guarantee that the generated HTML is safe.

As about your question about jQuery: `.val()` is not supposed to handle what you want. If you want to encode-decode things, you can do something like this:

```
function htmlEncode(value){
  //create a in-memory div, set it's inner text(which jQuery automatically encodes)
  //then grab the encoded contents back out.  The div never exists on the page.
  return $('<div/>').text(value).html();
}

function htmlDecode(value){
  return $('<div/>').html(value).text();
}

function myVal(context, v) {
    return v ? context.val(htmlEncode(v)) : htmlDecode(context.val());
}
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219860/html-encoding-in-javascript-jquery).

But whenever you need protection you need to have one at server-side. You can protect your client-side as well against XSS input, but that is optional.